# Oracle normalization

Tags: oracle, normalization

What are 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th normal form in Oracle databases?

Comment: I was about to close this as a duplicate, but after some searching I realized nobody asked "What is normalization" yet... clearly someone should ;)

Comment: Normalization is a *logical* modeling concept/technique, applicable to any relational database management system, of which Oracle is but one example.

Comment: In Oracle, you can use the very poorly documented `USING NORMAL FORM` clause of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @DCookie: Actually, normalization and relational design are applicable far beyond SQL database management systems. I used to have to work with Lotus Notes. Most of the problems I saw were the direct result of a flawed model, which could have been avoided by doing a good relational design first, then adapting its constraints to the Notes platform. If you read advanced books on OO programming, you'll recognize a lot of normalization problems that have nothing to do with databases. I'm not sure I'd say the relational model applies anywhere you persist data, but it's close.

Answer (score 3):

Use google and you will find answers in [OraFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Normalization), [Psoug](http://psoug.org/reference/normalization.html), [databases.about.com](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) and many, many more.

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially the extent of normalization of the database schema. Normalizing means to reduce reduncy between the tables in the schema. Wikipedia has a nice write up about over [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).